# python geopandas shapely file error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_geographic'

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, shapefile, geopandas

when I try to plot geometry from the shapefile I read.

```
data['geometry'].plot()
```

I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_geographic'
```

Any idea what is the issue. I have set crs to 4326 while creating the shapefile

here is my shp file
[image]

Comment: Hi, is this related to the problem discussed here  https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1311. Best

Comment: I checked the version of pyproj , its 2.6.1.post1

Comment: ok. Are you using geoplot https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/quickstart/quickstart.html ? Do you have minimal working example ? Best

Comment: did you fix this? could be an issue with the geometry column, encountered same error with POINTS and solved by reconstructing the column from lat long using fiona - was easy in my case more difficult here with polygons. Chased error for ages thinking it was a package error